# How to auto fill blank cells in column

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I need some help with Google Sheets.
I have two columns, let's say A1-A100 and C1-C100. In A1-A100 I have a list of names (students), but there may be less than 100, so it could be blank from A85 to A100 for example. In C1-C100 I have grades, from 0 to 10. I need a script that auto-fills blank cells in grades (C) column with "AUS" (short for 'not present' in Spanish). But only cells corresponding to some student... so from C85 to C100, it should be left blank.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Using the functions and classes from the Spreadsheet service [1], i made and tested the code for what you want to do:

```
function fill() {
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var values = tss.getRange("Sheet1!B1:B100").getValues();

  for(i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
    var value = values[i][0];

    if (value == "") {
      var rangeB = tss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(i+1,2);
      var rangeA = tss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(i+1,1);

      if(!rangeA.isBlank()) {
        rangeB.setValue("AUS");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That function needs to be inside a script bound to the Spreadsheet, then you can add a macro [2] so you can run the function from the Sheets UI.

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/macros

Answer (score -1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((A2:A<>"")*(B2:B=""), "AUS", B2:B))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hi! thank you for your reply. I need to auto fill blank spaces in B column, not clone the column with blank spaces filled, that's why I think I need a script.... Hope I explained myself well.